# Returning only one result per student using COUNT()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

First off, here's my database schema for the relevant tables:

```
table: students
record_number    |    forename    |    surname

table: applications
id    |    record_number    |    job_id    |    status_id
```

The `record_number` field in the `applications` table is a foreign key to the `students` table. I'm trying to write some SQL to generate a bar chart in APEX which shows the number of students who have an accepted internship and those who do not.

If a student has an accepted application, the `status_id` field is `7`. Anything else and they do not have an accepted application. Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT NULL AS link, 'Placed' AS label, COUNT(*) AS value
FROM tbl_students students
JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
WHERE applications.status_id = 7
UNION
SELECT NULL AS link, 'Unplaced' AS label, CASE COUNT(*) AS value WHEN value > 1 THEN 1 END
FROM tbl_students students
JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
WHERE applications.status_id != 7
```

The problem is, a student can have many internships, and only one of them can be accepted at once. This is fine for the first query above. However, a student can have many unaccepted internships, and the second query counts them all instead of counting just once (to show that +1 student doesn't have an unaccepted internship).

How can I adapt the query to only count students without an accepted internhip once rather than counting them to however many unnacepted internships they have? I tried with the `CASE` statement but it's throwing a syntax error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want the second query to be something like this

```
SELECT NULL AS link, 'Unplaced' AS label, COUNT(DISTINCT students.record_number) AS value
  FROM tbl_students students
       JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
 WHERE applications.status_id != 7
```

This will count the number of distinct `students.record_number` values.  Since that is the primary key of the `students` table, I would expect that to give you the number of students that have at least one unaccepted internship.

If that query does not produce the results you are looking for, it would be helpful if you could post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: That's closer to what I need, but according to this query there are 7 students when only 6 are actually in the database. To explain further, if 4 students have accepted internships, the query should return `(null) | Unplaced | 2` and `(null) | Placed | 4`.

Comment: @JamesDawson - Well, then we're probably going to need to see the data.  Ideally in the form of `DDL` and `DML` statements or a fiddle on www.sqlfiddle.com that we can play with.